# application getting slower when getting data from service in KITKAT android version

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

The application is working good in lower than 4.4.2 version in android. when am running application in 4.4.2 version device application is very slow while getting/calling data from the web service.

Is anyone facing this kind problem? please help me if have solution for this.

following is my code to attachemnt uploading.

private class UploadAttachmentTask extends AsyncTask {

```
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    int result = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean res) {
        super.onPostExecute(res);
        if (!ApplicationData.isOffline())
            dialog.dismiss();
        updateData(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (!ApplicationData.isOffline()) {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(EvidenceDetailActivity.this);
            dialog.setMessage("Uploading resource...");
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.setProgress(0);
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

    // posting image audio, video file to server
    public int postMediaDataToServer(String evidenceId, File file) {
        String fileName = service.createFileNameWithDate(file);
        System.gc();
        int result = postAttachmentToServer(fileName, file, evidenceId);
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public int postAttachmentToServer(String fileName, File file,
            String evidenceId) {
        try {
            System.gc();
            HttpURLConnection conn = null;
            DataOutputStream dos = null;
            DataInputStream inStream = null;

            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "----WebKitFormBoundarysNDKBMUFqqvzYWGh";

            byte[] buffer;
            try {
                long fileSize = file.length();
                int bufferSize = 1024 * 512;
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
                URL url = new URL(CacheAPI.mediaURL());


                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                //conn.setChunkedStreamingMode(bufferSize);
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
                conn.setRequestProperty("X-Ecordia-Software", "ecordiApp");
                List<Cookie> cookies = ApplicationData.getCookieStore()
                        .getCookies();
                if (cookies.size() > 0)
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", cookies.get(0)
                            .getName() + "=" + cookies.get(0).getValue());

                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"EvidenceIdentifier\""
                        + lineEnd + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(evidenceId + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                if (fileName.endsWith(".jpg")) {
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd
                            + lineEnd);
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".mp4")) {
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: video/mp4" + lineEnd
                            + lineEnd);
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".3gp")) {
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: video/3gp" + lineEnd
                            + lineEnd);
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".mov")) {
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: video/quicktime"
                            + lineEnd + lineEnd);
                } else if (fileName.endsWith(".wav")) {
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"File0\"; filename=\""
                            + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: audio/wav" + lineEnd
                            + lineEnd);
                }
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
                int bytesRead = 0;
                long count = 0;
                while ((bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    count = count + bufferSize;
                    publishProgress((int) ((count * 100) / fileSize));
                }
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd + twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
                        + lineEnd);
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                LogService.appendLog(Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            try {

                inStream = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                String str;
                while ((str = inStream.readLine()) != null) {
                }
                inStream.close();
                conn.disconnect();
                return 0;
            } catch (Exception ioex) {
                LogService.appendLog(Log.getStackTraceString(ioex));
                return 2;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogService.appendLog(Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return 2;
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            LogService.appendLog(Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        dialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(File... params) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!ApplicationData.isOffline()) {
            try {
                result = postMediaDataToServer(
                        mCurrentEvidence.getEvidenceIdentifier(), params[0]);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if (isOfflineEvidence) {
            List<OfflineEvidence> offlineEvidences;

            if (ApplicationData.isAssessor()) {
                offlineEvidences = LoginActivity.assessorOfflineEvidenceDataSource
                        .getAllOfflineEvidences(
                                ApplicationData.getCandidateName(),
                                ApplicationData.getApiPortfolioId());
            } else {
                offlineEvidences = offlineDataSource
                        .getAllOfflineEvidences(ApplicationData
                                .getApiPortfolioId());
            }

            if (evidenceDate != null) {
                for (OfflineEvidence offlineEvidence : offlineEvidences) {
                    if (offlineEvidence.getDate().equals(evidenceDate)) {
                        service.storeMediaToDataBase(offlineEvidence,
                                params[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: without code its difficult tell what causes the slow down.

Comment: Posted code of uploading. when am uploading an image/video/audio file this is getting stuck in 4.4.2 version. working well in below versions